# i have a login page with profile page that not working

Tags: php, mysql, session

i have a login page that allow user to enter email and password then submit and the system check if data is correct it display the profile page and if not it display a message inform the user that the data are not correct .

but the problem is that if i put   **header("Location:profile.php");** the system do not work 
but if i echo a message that inform user that the data are correct the browser display this message without any problem

## login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('include/connect.php');
//$message = ""; 
if(!empty($_POST['email']))
{

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$email = strip_tags($email);
$pass = strip_tags($pass);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
//$pass = md5($pass);

$sql=mysql_query( "SELECT user_id, email_address, first_name FROM user WHERE email_address='$email'AND password='$pass'LIMIT 1") or die("error in user table");
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

  if($login_check > 0)
  {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

          $id = $row['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;

          $firstname = $row['first_name'];
          $_SESSION['first_name']= $firstname;

          $email = $row['email_address'];
          $_SESSION['email_address']= $email;

          mysql_query("UPDATE user SET last_log_date=now() WHERE user_id='$id'");

        //$message = "correct email and passworddd!!";  
          header("Location:profile.php");
          exit();     
  }//close if 
  else
  {
      //$message = "incorrect Email or Password!!";
      //exit();
  }
}//close if

?>
```

## profile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
 require_once('include/connect.php'); 


if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['user_id'];
    var_dump($id);

}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    $id= $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

else
{
    print "Important  data  are missing";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    exit();

}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user  WHERE user_id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

   $firstname=$row['first_name'];
   $lastname=$row['last_name'];
   $birth_date=$row['birth_date'];
   $registered_date=$row['registered_date'];
   //***************for upload img*****************//
   $check_pic="members/$id/image01.jpg";
   $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
   if(file_exists($check_pic))
   {
       $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"100px\"/>";
   }
   else
   {
       $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\">";
   }
   echo $id, $firstname, $birth_date;
?>
```

Comment: Is your login checks are correct? Mean you are getting correct info about registered users?

Comment: "does not work" - you'll need to be a lot more specific than that.

Comment: It would help if we knew how exactly it "does not work". What was the error message?

Comment: Can you please look into the error log which is located at /var/log/apache2/ in debian based systems?

Comment: @user2207792 yes are correct it is just the redirect problem    header("location: profile.php"); this is the problem and i have tried from yesterday until now to fix this error without any success

Comment: read http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Answer (score 0):

use `ob_end_flush()` before php close tag `?>`

Comment: i did used ob_end_flush() but still the same problem

Comment: please try remove `exit()`

Comment: i remove the exit()  but still having the same problem

Comment: are you sure, your `select` statement results a row? perhaps `$login_check` is 0

Comment: @ amir no i did a var_dump for the $ id $  firstname and email and all it return the correct data

Comment: are you sure your `update` is successful? if not try using `or die(mysql_error());` at the end of your `update` statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript there to redirect on profile page. because if any small mistake like printing before or any space php header() function can cause some problem.. so better user javascript there.

check with bellow code

```
?>
<script>
window.location.href="profile.php";
</script>
<?
```

Comment: just comment your headerfunction and copy this code and paste there.. and run your code.

Comment: I think the better od actual way is output buffering .... not js ... how ever it will work to ..if js is not disabled

Comment: yes you are right but its a quick way because if we have error in php header, then its very difficult to find and also its take lots of time to check.

Answer (score 0):

I have doubt in this line of profile.php

`require_once('include/connect.php');`

If path of profile.php is faulty, you have to change things in your

`header(Location: "xyz/profile.php");`

Please check that this relative path is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('include/connect.php');
//$message = ""; 
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{

 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];

 $email1 = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($email));
 $pass1 = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($pass));
 //$pass = md5($pass);

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, email_address, first_name FROM user WHERE email_address='$email1' AND password='$pass1' LIMIT 1") or die("error in user table");
 $login_check = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)

if($login_check)
{
   $row = $login_check;

      $id = $row['user_id'];
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;

      $firstname = $row['first_name'];
      $_SESSION['first_name']= $firstname;

      $email = $row['email_address'];
      $_SESSION['email_address']= $email;

      mysql_query("UPDATE user SET last_log_date=now() WHERE user_id='$id'");

    //$message = "correct email and passworddd!!";  
      header("Location: profile.php");
      exit();     
}//close if 
else
{
  //$message = "incorrect Email or Password!!";
  //exit();
}
}//close if

?>
```

Comment: @user2360853 Please give space after colon like header("Location: profile.php");

Comment: @user2360853 See my update answer and try. if any problem then let me know.